# Overwriting a rule in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I'm writing a spreadsheet to record when products are ordered, when they arrive and whether or not they're overdue, how late they were etc, and I need a little help:

Really dumb question here, but I'm using the formula "= AND ( $M6 = "" , $E6 < TODAY ())" to highlight a row (no fill, bold red text) if the product is overdue, which works great but it also highlights the rows we're not yet using.

I tried to counteract it by writing another rule, using the formula "= IF ( $D6 = ISBLANK ())" as column D is always filled if the row is in use, and setting the format to appear with white fill and regular black text.

However, this doesn't appear to be working? I made sure the second rule exceeded the first, but it is still having no effect.

I've also tried the formula $D6 = "", with the same result

Also, I am using M6/E6/D6 as row 6 is the first entry. I tried using M1/E1/D1, but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=AND($M1="",$E1<TODAY(),NOT(ISBLANK($D1)))
```

for Format values where this formula is true:

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you're looking for, while not highlighting rows where column E is not yet populated.

```
=AND($M6="", $E6<TODAY(), $E6<>"")
```

Answer (score -1):

=ISblank returns a boolean TRUE or FALSE, so you would have to make your if statement say something like: If Isblank($D6) = TRUE,something,something else)

For example, I just tested this out and it returns 'Hello' and 'bye' where appropriate:

```
 =IF(ISBLANK(D1)=TRUE, "Hello","bye")
```

Comment: What would I use instead of ISBLANK because this formula is in conditional formatting, due to it needing to change the colour of the cell without changing the actual content, so a formula with multiple outcomes isn't possible